# Florida Drivers License and Netherlands rental car

Tags: car-rentals, netherlands

I would like to rent a rental car: if I have a FL drivers license, should I expect to be able rent a car in the NL?  I am interested in renting from SIXT, however, I am also interested in understanding what the expectation for any rental car in the NL.

Comment: Keep in mind that most rental cars in The Netherlands are stick shift and you will probably need to pay more if you want to rent an automatic car.

Comment: @JaneDoe1337: good advice that helps the community

Answer (score 5):

You can use a US drivers license for up to six months in the Netherlands. Rental companies will normally rent to you based on a US license, assuming you are within that period.

Comment: If you will leave Netherlands at all during your visit, check the attitudes of other countries about an International Driving Permit (IDP).  Some countries demand it; others prefer your "real" license,

Comment: You always have to have your real license with your IDP, but it never hurts to have the IDP with it as well. (I would suggest getting one if you travel to any country where English is not the first or very widely used second language.)

Comment: WIthout your real license, the IDP is just a colorful piece of paper. The IDP merely serves as a translation of your license, it is not a permit.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can rent a car in the Netherlands with any US Driver License.

In practical terms, renting a car in Western Europe is the same as renting in North America.  There are local/state variations, but those exist here.